# alternative to SVN Merge

Tags: .net

I find the whole process of merging two projects (one committed to SVN the other not) very lengthy. Manual changes are too many and too hard to make the new merged project compile. Is there any alternative to this ? The project that is not Checked into SVN has a backup. I do not want to use softwares such as Python etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I faced a situation like this (was splitting workspaces across PVCS and SVN at a client) I used [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) to merge the files and folders. There are other great tools out there like DeltaWalker, DiffMerge, etc, but Beyond Compare was my favorite. I wish they would port it to OS X.

Answer (score 1):

So, doing it manually is too hard. And you don't want to use software.

Then ...

1. what *do* you want to use?
2. If you don't want to use software, why are you asking on a programming website?